# How to compare two same or different MongoDB Object ids in php

Tags: php, mongodb, object, bson

Hi I am trying to compare `MongoDB` data on basis of it's Object ids but in both operators `==` and `===` it return true even when value is different.

I am trying to find similar `_id` values when  I get my first `_id` value it will store `_id` somewhere and then it will start finding same `_id` value throughout the collection and it will print all the similar `_id` value

**like my value -**

```
    MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                (
                    [oid] => 5fca7fe7082ba613cfee876a
                )

            [title] =>  Dave
            [job] => seller
)
)

MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                (
                    [oid] => 5fee876a5fca7fe7082ba613c
                )

            [title] =>  louis
            [job] => gardner
)
)
```

When I am comparing these **values it return true** .

```
         foreach($cursor as $row){
                
                      if($row['_id'] === $row['_id']){

                          echo 'yes';
                      }else{
                          echo 'no';
                      }
                    }
```

Suggest any better value to compare [oid]values.

I am trying to print $row value only if `row['_id']` is similar to another if it find more than one then it will print all the value which is similar to one anothr `$row['id]`

Comment: You've posted the same question again, without attempting to correct the errors we've pointed out in the previous one. When you do `$row['_id'] === $row['_id']` you are comparing the **same value to itself**. Of course it will always be true. You would need to memorize the previous id in an external variable (outside of the loop) in order to be able to compare it to the current loop element id.

Comment: @El_Vanja apologies, I am clueless how can I initialize or compare this, if you could please suggest with an example

Comment: also variables are same but their values are different in `$row['_id']` so how can it be true ?

Comment: I believe you need to go through some basic tutorials (or redo them if you have). A variable can't have two values at the same time. What's happening here is that when your loop moves to the next iteration, the previous `$row` values are overwritten with the current values. I think it would be better if you rephrased your question to reflect what you're trying to do and then maybe we can suggest a proper way of going about it.

Comment: I am trying to print `$row` value when one `$row['id]` is similar to another `$row['id]`  if it finds more than one then still it will print all the similar values

Comment: Since `_id` is a _unique_ identifier, I doubt you'll find any documents with the same value, If it was possible, it would defeat the purpose of the id and basically would make MongoDB useless.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no i have store `oid` in _id which is not unique

Comment: The `oid` _is_ the unique id.

Comment: it's a small output which I have shown her i have many cases where `oid` is unique so what will I do in these case

Comment: If you have multiple documents with the same `oid`, I would say that there's something seriously wrong since MondoDB doesn't, for obvious reasons, support duplicate ids. The `oid` value is the actual  unique id.

Comment: _"i have many cases where oid is unique"_ - They should _all_ be unique so showing us that is pointless. Show us examples of the id's _not_ being unique instead, since that's a state that shouldn't be able to happen.

Comment: Your intent is not clear. Instead of looking for a way to compare these values, try and edit the question to describe what you need this comparison *for*. Describe what your application should be doing here (give us the wider picture) and then maybe we'll be able to help you. What we know so far is not making a lot of sense to us.

Comment: I did unwind and so sort on query level so please suggest a way to compare values and print

Comment: Here I am comparing one `oid` with others if similar found print similar `oid` values

Comment: That didn't clarify anything. Do you actually understand what we've written in our comments? I honestly believe this is a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) that stems from lack of your understanding how things work (not trying to be rude, just honest.) But we can't know since we don't have a proper context. Edit your question and include a _detailed_ explanation of your actual issue like what exactly are you trying to compare and _why_. You should also include some data that you're having issues with. Clear examples are better than vague explanations.

Comment: I am trying to find similar _id values when I get my first _id value it will store _id somewhere and then it will start finding same _id value throughout the collection and it will print all the similar _id value